# MySQL Binlog increases beyond normal specified

Tags: mysql, filesize, binlog

i have binlog enabled for mysql 5.7 and i am seeing that some files are created twice for the same time (one is 100 mb other is 2.3GB) they were not being done previously the bin log size is 100 mb as can be seen from other files(please see attachment with this post).the last file is being written .are the highlighted files wrong or ? please can anyone explain ,thanks[binlog files yellow marked are increases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8frit.png)

enabled General query log

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html says:

> A binary log file may become larger than `max_binlog_size` if you are using large transactions because a transaction is written to the file in one piece, never split between files.

This means if you change many rows in a single transaction, or the rows contain very large data values (e.g. long BLOB or TEXT content), a single binary log could grow far past the supposed limit on the size.

Comment: Hi Bill ,hope you have seen the image with this question ,i.e there are two files created at the same time 14.12-2023 7.26 ,is that normal that two binlog creates at the same time,one is normal (100mb) other is 2.3GB,is there any way i can check if there were large data values (long,BLOB,Text) ? general query log ,thanks

Comment: The two files may be created within 1 second. That is, `bin.009947` was created and then less than 1 second later it was full (102MB) and then `bin.00948` was created. The file timestamps only have 1-second granularity, so this hides the fact that they are not created at exactly the same time.

Comment: You can use `mysqlbinlog` to examine the content of the files read the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html. You can also read the source code of the client application that is making changes to your database. It's up to you to have knowledge of the activity running on your database.